# How to properly close a PreparedStatment & ResultSet in an Iterator?

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, jdbc, dispose

When I implement a custom `Iterator<T>` that needs to use a `PreparedStatement` and a `ResultSet` that both are closeable how do I correctly close them?

```
    fun select(): Sequence<Item> = object : Sequence<Item> {
        val result = stmt.executeQuery() // <-- needs to be closed too
        override fun iterator() = object : Iterator<Item> {
            val select = File("sql/select.sql").readText()
            override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun next(): Item {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I also somehere need to place this:

```
val stmt = sqliteConnection.prepareStatement(select)
// ... do something
stmt .close()
```

Or wouldn't I close it here at all, but make the class itself `AutoCloseable`? This would be an option for the `PreparedStatment`. However, the `ResultSet` still remains open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question sounds a bit too broad, but I'll try to answer your specific points.

**Closing the Statement**
You ask if you should make your class AutoCloseable instead. Whatever you do, you'll still need to close the Statement *somewhere*. If you make your class AutoCloseable, you'll need to close the Statement in your `close()` function. Otherwise, you'll have to find somewhere else to close the Statement - it depends on how your class is structured (which you don't show in your question) but making it AutoCloseable sounds sensible.

**Closing the ResultSet**
You might not have to close the ResultSet because it will be automatically closed when you close the Statement. However, if you call your `select()` function many times, possibly with different inputs, you might want to close the ResultSet to release resources sooner instead of relying on them being eventually closed. You can do that in your `hasNext()` function: if it returns `false`, you can close the ResultSet.

Some other, general information:

- instead of manually overriding the `iterator()` function, you can use the  [sequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/sequence.html) builder function, and just `yield` each row. This will make the code much more succinct and readable.
- it looks as if you're trying to reinvent the wheel with your `select()` function. Have a look at existing libraries such as [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/) and [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) and see if they already do what you want.
- when you package your application, your `select.sql` file will probably be in the `resources` folder inside your `.jar` file. Then you won't be able to get the file using the `File` class. Use [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) instead.

Comment: Lot's of interesting things, especially the `sequence`!